# Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: No such domain at this location

Tags: c#, smtp

I'm using the following basic code:

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

msg.to.add("someone@hotmail.com");
msg.to.add("someone@gmail.com");
msg.to.add("someone@myDomain.com");

msg.From = new MailAddress("me@myDomain.com", "myDomain", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
msg.Subject = "subject";
msg.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
msg.Body = "body";
msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
msg.IsBodyHtml = false;

//Add the Creddentials
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "192.168.0.24"; 
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("me@myDomain.com", "password");
client.Port = 25;

try
{
   client.Send(msg);
}
catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpException ex)
{
    sw.WriteLine(string.Format("ERROR MAIL: {0}. Inner exception: {1}", ex.Message,  ex.InnerException.Message));
}
```

Problem is the mail is only sent to the address in my domain (someone@mydomain.com) and I get the following exception for the 2 other addresses:

System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: No such domain at this location

I suspect it's something to do with something blocking my smtp client but not sure how to approach this. 
Any idea? thanks!

Comment: The only thing that looks peculiar is the Host - it looks like a router IP address. The Host should be the name or IP address of the host used for SMTP transactions. Can you use mail.myDomain.com as a test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ron is correct,just use the 587 port and it will work as u wish.

Check this code and see if it works:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

                mail.From = new MailAddress("your_email_address@gmail.com");
                mail.To.Add("to_address@mfc.ae");
                mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
                mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL";

                SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can u send me your project zip so that i can take a look and get you the issues

Comment: Hi Vipin, I'm sorry but I can't send the whole project zip. Also this port is not working, this time with a different exception (It cannot connect at all...). One more thing - I tried to run the same process from another server, using the old port (25) and it works fine. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Try using port=587. Here's useful related link: http://mostlygeek.com/tech/smtp-on-port-587/comment-page-1/

Comment: Hi Ron and @Vipin, thanks for your reply but unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem. I still get the same error. Any other idea?

Comment: Try adding to SmtpClent: client.DefaultCredentials = false;

Comment: Hi Ron, Still not working. Trying this client.DefaultCredentials = false with both ports and also the EnableSsl = true.

Comment: @rontornambe the url you posted returns  a 404 not found